# What are the tabs on this face-plate for?

Tags: electrical

The [Steel City RS-6](http://tnb.com/ps/fulltilt/index.cgi?company=TNB&part=RS8) 4" face plate has metal tabs that break-off easily. What is their purpose?

[image]

(click for full-size)

As you can see, they are cut and bent to leave a gap/slot.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are actually nuts, even though they are an odd shape.

They mount behind the receptacle to grab the screw and sandwich it to the cover. The screw goes through the cover, then through the receptacle, and threads into the tab. The offset dog on the tab should secure under the cover edge. This lets you use the screws on the top and bottom of the receptacle to secure it to the cover.

See the instruction sheet from the manufacturer:
http://www-public.tnb.com/shared/inst/TA01413-TB2.pdf

Comment: So you attach the receptacle to the faceplate rather than the faceplate to the receptacle?  I like it.

Comment: @BMitch: In fact, you can sit at a workbench and do all the work to prep the receps. Check it out: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nyujc.jpg

Comment: exactly right, but wiring the side terminals is difficult after the recpt is attached to plate. Could work that way however.

Comment: It's not too hard if you only put 1 recep in the face plate. I'm putting two receps at each location (so nice!) but it means wiring the receps up before putting them in the face plate. Again, all at the workbench.